# NoSuchKey when getting a signed url for a cloudstorage object with a space in the name

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

The app engine code below uses app_identity.sign_blob() to request a signed url. This code works fine, when there is no space in the GCS filename. 
A space is allowed in [object names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-naming#objectnames). For testing I used the SDK.

I've seen a lot of questions about this issue, but I could not create a solution

Is it a bug or?

```
def sign_url(bucket_object, expires_after_seconds=6, bucket=default_bucket):

    method = 'GET'
    gcs_filename = urllib.quote('/%s/%s' % (bucket, bucket_object))
    content_md5, content_type = None, None

    # expiration : number of seconds since epoch
    expiration_dt = datetime.utcnow() +    timedelta(seconds=expires_after_seconds)
    expiration = int(time.mktime(expiration_dt.timetuple()))

    # Generate the string to sign.
    signature_string = '\n'.join([
        method,
        content_md5 or '',
        content_type or '',
        str(expiration),
        gcs_filename])

    signature_bytes = app_identity.sign_blob(signature_string)[1]

    # Set the right query parameters. we use a gae service account for the id
    query_params = {'GoogleAccessId': google_access_id,
                    'Expires': str(expiration),
                    'Signature': base64.b64encode(signature_bytes)}

    # Return the built URL.
    result = '{endpoint}{resource}? {querystring}'.format(endpoint=GCS_API_ACCESS_ENDPOINT,
                                                          resource=gcs_filename,    
                                                          querystring=urllib.urlencode(query_params))
return result
```

Update. The response when I use the signed url:

```
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

Comment: Just a theory, but it looks like you're using the unescaped object name. I believe the gcs_filename section needs to be the path portion of the URL, which means the object name should be URL-escaped, i.e. replace the space with a plus sign. Lemme know if that does it.

Comment: gcs_filename is escaped for the signature and the resource (= path) using urllib.quote() in the above code. I also thave tried urllib.quote_plus().

Comment: What about urllib.quote_plus(path, safe='/') ?  quote_plus escapes the slash by default.

Comment: Thnx, I already tried it.

Comment: From this older post (PHP) it seems that signing doesn't like urlencoding either, but works when replacing spaces with '%20': http://stackoverflow.com/a/26715777

Comment: I have tried it and it did not work. I also tried to escape the %, escaping the gcsfilename and not the signature. No success.

Comment: What is the symptom of it failing when it doesn't work? It's unclear what the error is. Does it crash? Give an invalid signature? Something else?

Comment: I have updated my question with the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem has been solved.**

I do not know why. I did not change anything.
You can try the GAE app using the code below and this link:

```
https://voscausa-gae.appspot.com/download_signed?bucket_object=download/test signed1 .txt
```

The code is here: [appengine-gcs-signed-url](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-signed-url)

You can also use a signed url with a policy document for a direct upload to GCS.
The code: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload